# sig STOP to process with timeout in Perl

Tags: perl

Is that possible to send a SIG STOP to a process ID through a perl script and then , if some time passed, lets say 1 minute , to send a SIG CONT to the PID unless "someone else" already send this SIG CONT to the process?

thanks.

Answer (score 2):

A process can use the `waitpid` syscall (with the `WUNTRACED`/`WCONTINUED` flags) to monitor when a child process was stopped/resumed. This only works if the monitored process is a child of the original process. But regardless of being a child or not, you can always send the signals `SIGSTOP`/`SIGCONT` to other processes (provided that they are owned by the same user). If a process has resumed running because it received a `SIGCONT`, it is totally harmless to send a second `SIGCONT`. So you could just do

```
kill 'STOP',$pid or die "cannot send STOP signal: $!";
sleep 60;
kill 'CONT',$pid or die "cannot send CONT signal: $!";
```

and not worry about the second signal.

Comment: Hi , not quite , cause in the middle of the 60 seconds sleep , someone can send CONT signal , and then STOP signal again , so the "first" sleep will be initiated and the sleep is be less the 60 seconds.. I hope I'm clear enough. @redneb

Comment: @Mojo Your requirements are very unclear. You have to gives us some more details.